# nth child find not a function

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

```js
var a = document.getElementById('img0');
console.log(a);
 var x = a.find(':nth-child(' + 1 + ')');
 console.log(x);
```

```html
Using just javascript I'm trying to get the first child.  The code below says that find is not a function

<div id="img0" class="det-img">
  <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/uploads/acu2020-img1-1200X800.jpg ">
</div>
```

Comment: `find` works on Array so you need to use `querySelector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the first occuring child node, you should use `a.querySelector('*:nth-child(1)'`, for example, not `a.find(...)`. The `.find()` method is probably what you're familiar with if you've used jQuery before, but that method does not exist on elements.

[`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector) will attempt to find the first match of the supplied selector among your element's descendant nodes.

See the updated proof-of-concept code below:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('img0')
var x = a.querySelector('*:nth-child(' + 1 + ')');
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div id="img0" class="det-img">
  <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/uploads/acu2020-img1-1200X800.jpg ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element's children property to do that, no need for querySelector.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('img0');
console.log(a);
 var x = a.children[0];
 console.log(x);
```

```html
Using just javascript I'm trying to get the first child.  The code below says that find is not a function

<div id="img0" class="det-img">
  <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/uploads/acu2020-img1-1200X800.jpg ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use 'firstElementChild' for this purpose. As per mdn the ParentNode.firstElementChild is a read-only property that returns the object's first child Element, or null if there are no child elements.

Below is the working code snippet:

```
 document.getElementById("img0").firstElementChild
```